# Chai versus should.js with Mocha for Node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I see articles using Chai, but should.js comes from TJ Holowaychuk, maker of Express and Mocha, which is an excellent pedigree.  Should I use Chai or should.js with Mocha for a new Node.js server-side only project?

Comment: Welcome to SO ;-) I think this is not the right place for questions like this as it attracts subjective answers. In my experience, which you use does not really matter -- it must fit your style of development but I had quite good experiences with both of them.

Comment: Chai actually has the should interface, so I would say Chai is the way to go

Comment: [mocha.js docs themselves state](https://mochajs.org/#assertions) that they use should.js

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the end there are only few differences in the API. Generally I would tend to chai.js because:

- development is more active (pull requests are ignored at should.js)
- chai.expect is more consistent as possible to use on "undefined" and "null"

However it does not make a big difference.

Comment: https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js/graphs/contributors

Comment: In general you should perfer `chai`

Comment: lol why did he say PR's are ignored. That doesn't appear true from their github site.